# Prepared statement with wildcard not returning certain rows but query returns all rows?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I'm using JTDS as a driver to connect to SQL server.

Here's the query that's giving me problems:

```
SELECT EmpID,FirstName,LastName,CompanyName,DepartmentName,JobTitle,HireDate FROM Employees where UPPER(FirstName) LIKE 'KEVIN%'
```

It returns 2 rows on SQL Server. One that has 'KEVIN' in upper case and another that has 'Kevin' like so. I used the wildcard to make sure I get both results. In my EmployeeDAO class I'm using the following:

```
        ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT EmpID,FirstName,LastName,CompanyName,"
                + "DepartmentName,JobTitle,HireDate FROM Employees WHERE UPPER(FirstName) LIKE ?");
        ps.setString(1, FirstName + "%");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

And then of course I put KEVIN on my main. It only returns ONE row, which is the 'Kevin' row.

How do I fix this so it returns all rows?

Comment: How are you collecting the rows from `ResultSet`? The problem is most likely in there.

Comment: Have you tried:

SELECT EmpID,FirstName,LastName,CompanyName,DepartmentName,JobTitle,HireDate 
FROM Employees 
WHERE UPPER(FirstName) LIKE UPPER('KEVIN%')

Comment: `while(rs.next()) { v.add(new Employee(rs.getInt("EmpID"), rs.getString("FirstName"), rs.getString("LastName"), rs.getString("CompanyName"), rs.getString("DepartmentName"), rs.getString("JobTitle"), rs.getString("HireDate"))); }` RS is the resultset and v is a Vector

Comment: By the way, have you tried `ps.setString(1, "'"+ FirstName + "%'");` (with quotes)

Comment: Yea that shouldn't make a difference considering jdbc handles single quotes and escapes for us

Comment: blah i just saw what's wrong just post your comment as an answer @BalusC. I guess that while that's filling the vector is causing problems. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Jean: the `PreparedStatement` takes care about this (and more). @Nim: OK, I reposted it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks fine (although I would uppercase the parameter value before setting it, to make it more robust). The problem is just in the way how you're collecting the rows from the `ResultSet`. Likely you're plain overriding the previous row with the next row so that you end up with only one row (the last one) in your collection.

Comment: You were right, but I was collecting the rows fine. It was in displaying that I messed up. Call it a brain fart if anything, but I ran a for loop and initiated the counter variable at 1. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Default collation of the SQL Server installation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and it is not case sensitive.

Change collation of the query:

```
SELECT Col1
FROM Table1
WHERE Col1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS LIKE 'KEVIN%'
```

Comment: Sadly the SQL Server I'm developing in _is actually_ case sensitive for some reason since my queries do not return upper case values which is why I had to do them the way I did.